# jQuery UI и overflow

Tags: jquery-ui, css

Есть такой код

```
<div id="templates_block" style="position: fixed; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:auto; top:270; right:30px; border: 1px solid black; height:47%; width: 300px;></div>
```

В него с помощью **ajax** **append**'ом добавляются элементы **span**. Их может быть сколько угодно много, потому стоит в стиле **overflow**.
C помощью **jQuery-UI** мне надо перетащить один из **span**'ов в другое место на странице (конкретно в textarea). Так суть проблемы вот в чем. **SPAN** перемещается только в пределах родителя-**div**'а, просто прокручивая его. А вот если у родителя убрать **overflow**, то все ок, но если **span**'ов много, то они естественно вылазят за пределы **div**, а это уже не пойдет.

**`containment: 'parent'`** и **`containment: 'window'`** в свойствах draggable() - не помогают.

**UPDATE:**

В общем решение нашел сам, вопрос закрыт.

Может кому пригодится.

Чтобы можно было перетащить элемент за пределы родителя с overflow, надо метод draggable() писать со следующими свойствами.

```
.draggable({scroll:false, helper: "clone", zIndex: 999, appendTo: "body"});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте

`.draggable({helper:'clone'})`

и уже с клоном работать дальше

Comment: Неа, родитель перестал растягиваться, но вынести span за его пределы нельзя